# PostgreSQL query for calculating rotisserie baseball points

Tags: sql, postgresql, ranking, window-functions

I am trying to write a PostgreSQL query to calculate fantasy baseball points, as described [here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/fantasy-baseball/rotisserie-roto-scoring-explained-sln6187.html).  What I have so far is available in [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0162/11), which calculates the points for each statistic correctly, except in the case of ties.  Points for teams that are tied are supposed to be calculated like so:

> In the case of a tie, each team involved receives an average of the total points due — i.e., in the above example, if two teams were tied for first in a category, each would receive 9.5 points [(10 + 9) / 2 = 9.5].

You can see the errors in my approach in the [first](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0162/11/0) and [second](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0162/11/1) result sets in my SQLfiddle.  In the first result set, the teams tied with 9 home runs should each get 3.5 points (sum of ranks 4 and 3 == 7, divided by 2) while in the second set, the teams tied with 33 RBI should also each get 3.5 (sum of ranks 5, 4, 3, and 2 == 14, divided by 4).

What would be the simplest way to correct these errors, and distribute the total points evenly among teams tied in the rankings of each statistic?

Comment: Can you explain what is `hr` and what is `rbi` in your schema? Also, if you're aiming and floating scores (like `9.5`), why do you use `integer` and not `numeric` type?

Comment: HR and RBI are the values I want to rank over -- in this case, [home runs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_run) and [runs batted in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_batted_in) for baseball teams.  These are integers, but in the case of a tie, the rankings of the teams should be averaged together, as in the Yahoo link in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, provided example is not a complete one, it'd be nice to have a candidate key among the provided fields.

1. It is possible to use [any aggregate function as window one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html). This removes the necessity for the sub-query to count all rows in the table.

Consider the output of the following query:

```
SELECT 
    hr,rbi,
    rank() OVER h AS hr_rank,
    row_number() OVER h AS hr_rn,
    count(*) OVER () - rank() OVER h + 1 AS hr_aprx,
    rank() OVER r AS rbi_rank,
    row_number() OVER r AS rbi_rn,
    count(*) OVER () - rank() OVER r + 1 AS rbi_aprx,
    count(*) OVER () AS cnt
FROM 
    stats
WINDOW h AS (ORDER BY hr DESC), r AS (ORDER BY rbi DESC);
```

This query provides the same information as your first 2 queries. If you'll look into the `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` output for it, you'll see that table is being accessed only once.

I've named point columns as `%_aprx` here, for these are approximate points yet, we'll have to calculate the average.

2. Now, as we have prepared some data for further calculations, we'll have to use a sub-query. This is due to the fact, that we must use our `%_aprx` columns for data grouping. I will use [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) here, as I find named sub-queries looking better.

Consider this query ([also on sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0162/26)):

```
WITH ranks AS (
    SELECT 
        hr, rbi,
        rank() OVER h AS hr_rank,
        row_number() OVER h AS hr_rn,
        count(*) OVER () - rank() OVER h + 1 AS hr_aprx,
        rank() OVER r AS rbi_rank,
        row_number() OVER r AS rbi_rn,
        count(*) OVER () - rank() OVER r + 1 AS rbi_aprx,
        count(*) OVER () AS cnt
    FROM 
        stats
    WINDOW h AS (ORDER BY hr DESC), r AS (ORDER BY rbi DESC)
)
SELECT 
    hr, rbi,
    (avg(hr_rn) OVER h)::float AS hr_pts,
    (avg(rbi_rn) OVER r)::float AS rbi_pts,
    (avg(hr_rn) OVER h + avg(rbi_rn) OVER r)::float AS ttl_pts
FROM 
    ranks
WINDOW h AS (PARTITION BY hr_aprx), r AS (PARTITION BY rbi_aprx)
ORDER BY 
    ttl_pts DESC, hr_pts DESC;
```

I'm converting resulting type of `avg()` calls to `float` to get rid of the series of zeroes. You can choose to [use `round()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) instead here though.

I've also added 2 ordering conditions, for ordering just by `ttl_pts` is not enough.

Note, that in the outer query's window definitions `ORDER BY` is missed out on purpose. With it, you'll get a running average effect (you can change query and see yourself).

Comment: Brilliant!  Yes, my example was missing some details, but intentionally so.  I stripped it down to a "minimal working example", because the "table" I'm running this query on is actually the result of another complex nested query that aggregate the team results from individual games, and I didn't want to make the problem look more complex than it is.   With your solution I can either build a temporary table with the aggregate results periodically, or adapt it to run over the aggregate query.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A brute force method might be to calculate off the unadjusted rank, something like this:

```
select hr, sum(raw) / count(*)
  from (
      select hr,
             (select count(*) + 1 from stats) - row_number() over (order by hr desc) as raw
        from stats
    ) r
 group by hr
 order by hr desc
```

and join that with the stats table to get the points for a given score.

Comment: That's a good start, but it'll get quite unwieldy repeating that subquery (with joins) for each of the ten statistics.  Hopefully there's an easier way.

Comment: Unwieldy is not uncommon with SQL. Maybe it can be turned into a function somehow, where the stats column is a parameter.

Comment: Postgres is smart enough to avoid doing repetitive scans for the inner sub-query. You can confirm this by looking at the `EXPLAIN` output.